# why is my messages._id(collectionId) undefined when i click a button

Tags: meteor

Hello I have specific problem that I have tried debugging for long term but failed. I'am building group chatting application and have failed to capture the id of a specific message so that I can be delete it. in collection
`var currentMessage = this._id;` when I click a button or element.. I get undefined.
But if I use console.log(this) ==> I get the message object without the _id..

```
 Object { text: "hullo", channel: "scotch", timestamp: 1459708047949, user: null }.
```

Let me show  a specific part of the code but the whole chat application can allow people to send messages to specific channel

```
'click .delMe': function(event){
      //message = this.messagesId;
         event.preventDefault();
       //var currentMessageId = this._id;
       if (confirm("Delete this message")) {
           //var currentMessage = this; //1:45a.m it worked
            var currentMessage = this._id
```

Comment: Can you add your template?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
{{#each messages}}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        {{ text }}
        <button id={{_id}} class="delMe"> Delete</button>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
```

Then try to access to the id like this

```
event.currentTarget.id
```

Comment: @issam THanks for the help, sorry i had taken long to reply because of the hectic test and coursework week, I shall try this at night

Comment: @issam Thanks Thank i finally managed to capture the id of the message using the button. I was able to put in the messages template which had  each message.